# Происхождение слова "слобода"

Tags: этимология

Околица - это понятно, то, что за кольями (правильно?). А вот слобода — как я понимаю, ремесленный район города. Почему она так называется?

Comment: А что, с "околицей", которая "за кольями" все согласны? Есть же слово "около", корень "коло-" - вокруг, круг. При чем тут колья?

Comment: А где тут околица???
Околица - от "около", а оно, в свою очередь, от коло - круга, все верно.

Comment: @behemothus, не поняла. Автор начинает свой вопрос с того, что околица - потому что за кольями. Правда, выражает некоторую неуверенность.

Comment: >Автор начинает свой вопрос с того, что околица -    
  
Ну бред же очевидный... Я в общем-то автору и отвечал... Вам только потому, что Вы о том вспомнили.

Answer (score 2):

Первоначально слободами называли поселения с полным или частичным освобождением от повинностей. По современным понятиям, офшорная зона. От "свободы" и образовалось "слобода", в результате диссимиляции губных в и б (б > л).

Answer (score 1):

*Слобода* -- это старинный славянский вариант слова *свобода*.
Например, есть югославское имя Слободан, дословно означающее "свободен", т.е. свободный.

**Слобода**, выражаясь канцелярским языком, *как населённый пункт* -- это изначально посёлок **свободных**, не крепостных, крестьян.

Приведу пример. Бывали землевладельцы, которым принадлежали земли в непривлекательных или даже опасных для занятий сельским хозяйством местах. Чтобы поддерживать свою землю в каком-то цивилизованном виде, её отдавали желающим на ней работать на долгий срок, на 20, на 30 лет.

Читал как раз про слободы, что когда-то в Приднепровье южнее Киева во времена монголо-татарского ига и некоторое время после того, сельское хозяйство пришло в упадок. Сёла опустели, крестьяне из-за нередких *незваных гостей* большей частью разбежались. Господа владельцы земель уехали в более безопасные места. Поля-леса забросили. Потом господа решили разрешить тем кто посмелее на оговоренный срок селиться и **свободно**, без барщины, обрабатывать землю.

Когда настали времена поспокойнее, владельцы вернулись. А названия поселений со словом **Слобода** кое-где остались.

Comment: Слободы появились раньше чем на Руси появились даже зачатки крепостного права. В принципе это даже в вашем собственном ответе проскальзывает, потому что южнее Киева во время Ига и до присоединения к Москве (точнее распространение на левобережную Украину крепостного права произошло только при Екатерине II) никаких крепостных даже быть не могло.

Comment: >во время Ига и до присоединения к Москве (точнее распространение на левобережную Украину крепостного права произошло только при Екатерине II) никаких крепостных даже быть не могло.

Если понимать так, что крепостное право -- это когда крестьянин не может самовольно переселиться в другое место, то ДА, я был неточен.

Но у польских/литовских панов тоже были холопы. Не хочется сейчас копаться в книжках по истории. И на пана - владельца земли тоже работали. Припоминается что-то такое: *"Пятая копна -- пану"*. Ну или какая-то N-ая копна. То есть определённая часть своего урожая -- владельцу земли

Comment: То что вы описали - это повинность (налог). В слободах от повинностей полностью или частично освобождались.

Крепостные кр-не - это только ограниченные в передвижении. Вы ведь тоже государству платите процент от своего дохода, а также можете быть призваны на военную службу, но крепостным от этого не становитесь.

Comment: Вот, из словаря Ожегова. (Переписываю из бумажного, не электронного. Авось скорее будет, чем в Интернете искать). 

**СЛОБОДА**

1. До отмены крепостного права в России: большое село с некрепостным населением.

2. Посёлок около города, пригород (устар.)

Comment: Первые слободы появились на Руси ещё в Х веке, естественно за такое время, понятие слободы менялось. Для слободы XVIII- 1-й пол. XIX вв. определение Ожегова по большей части справедливо, но в вашем же ответе вы писали про изначальный смысл.

Comment: В книге, где упоминаются слободы в Приднепровье, на украинском, писалось о *панщине*. Посмотрел, проверил, слово "панщина" соответствует русскому "барщина".

Барщина в Польше **существовала**. В разные времена разной тяжести. Иногда совсем отсутствовала. Иногда была тяжёлой.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Барщина
Смотрим раздел "Барщина в Польше"

Comment: Например, цитата: "создался статут короля Яна Альбрехта 1496 г., которым сильно ограничивалась свобода передвижения крестьян, а за ним следует целый ряд законоположений, развивающих институт крепостничества."

"Варшавская генеральная конфедерация 1573 предоставила крестьян полному произволу помещиков. В XVI веке понемногу исчезает различие, существовавшее ранее между различными классами сельских жителей, и все они сливаются в одно понятие о «подданных» , в законодательстве же исчезает норма количества барщинных дней, а определение этого количества предоставляется усмотрению владельца."

Comment: @Nikolja, а при чём тут барщина и крепостное право? Барщина, оброк, право первой ночи и пр. - это разновидности повинностей (налогов), а не атрибут крепостничества. Эти повинности, в изменённом виде, мы и сейчас несём в виде налогов и призыва в армию.

Про Петрковский статут не знал, но к обсуждаемому вопросу он не относится, слободы и на Украние и в России появились задолго до какого-либо прикрепления крестьян к земле.

Comment: Господа, а можно тезисно - предмет спора?
Можно спорить о том связано ли "слобода" со "свободой", но приняв это за истину, выяснять на филологическом форуме подробности, о какой свободе - крепостной, повинностной или там оброчной - идет речь уже, имхо, излишне.

Answer (score 1):

Слобода — от свобода. Это никем не оспаривается.

Но коли уж зашла речь о причинах, то смею напомнить, что разговор изначально идет о периоде с XI-XII по XVI-XVII век (источники немного расходятся), когда всякого рода повинности были материальными и служебными.
Так вот, существовали т. н. черные (ремесленные и т. п.) и белые (стрелецкие и проч.) слободы, последние из которых были освобождены от всех государевых обязанностей, а первые — только от "налоговых" (оброчных и проч.).
Таким образом, общим для них было совсем не отсутствие крепостной (личной) зависимости, а всего лишь государевой повинности.  Детали, в коих я не силен, отдаю на откуп @Марку Изу.

Но этимологический момент, думаю, на этом можно закрыть окончательно.

Comment: Предмет спора в том, что @Nikolja написал, что слободы изначально "посёлок свободных, некрепостных крестьян". Я его поправил, а дальше понеслось )).

Comment: >"посёлок свободных, некрепостных крестьян".  
  
Это не вопрос этимологии. Но в принципе, если убрать "крестьян", то слободчане, понятно, вряд ли могли быть крепостными. Другое дело, что не эта "свобода" легла в основу названия.

Answer (score 1):

Восходит от индоарийского — **слобод** (*slobod|shlabaд|t|*), как и еврейское слово **шаббат** — свободный (день).
На др. русском: освобождать — слобод|з|ить.

Этнотопоним — Слободзея, село на берегу реки, возникшее после исхода воды (освобожденное от воды).

Т. о. слобода — это первоначальное слово **свобода**, а в узком смысле — свободные земледельцы.
https://dexonline.ro/definitie/slobod